# Play! Framework - model default vs explicit constructor?

Tags: playframework

I see two ways of creating a User object with his/her information:

1) explicit constructor - I call the `Application.getUserInfo()` 
method, whose corresponding view has a form for the user to enter his signup information:
name, user, password and call the `Application.createUser(String name, String email, String password)` which then calls the explicit constructor `new User(name, email, password)`. Clicking the submit button would call `Application.createUser()` method.

2) If I call `Application.getUserInfo(User user)` method, does the corresponding view have a User object (created by the implicit default constructor)? In that case I can just read
user.name, user.email, user.password
This way I don't have to define an explicit constructor.

Could someone tell me if approach 2) is valid? If yes, are there any drawbacks to it, compared to 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches are valid, however approach number two may become a security problem.

With approach #2 you have to specify which properties may not be bound (a blacklist using the @NoBinding annotation) while in approach #1 you explicitly say which data is going to be bound (whitelisting).

Traditional secure software systems should be build around whitelisting... every firewall works in that way "block everything except what I specify" ...

If your app is just an intranet app, its probably okay to go with approach #2, if its a real world app facing thousands of users, I (personally) would go with approach #1.

Answer (score 1):

Approach 2 is valid and a very common approach. If you take a look at http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers#binding and look at the POJO binding for full information.

The only downside is that it exposes the structure of your models to people who can read your HTML, know you are using POJO binding and can work it out from there...but not sure that really matters.